# Cycles Render in viewport extremely slow?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu, performance

I have two 2080 TIs (both are checked on in the system settings), but cycles takes minutes to becone visible enough through the render noise to see my scene. This doesnt seem right to me....is it,

Octane and Keyshot rebder viewports are near intantaneous with my two gpus, so i dont know why cycles isnt the same.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean you have your GPUs selected under CUDA settings, or OptiX, or both? Also, do you have your Cycles settings set to GPU compute?

Comment: Hey Christopher, i've got both GPUs enabled in bother the Cuda and OptiX panels (Cuda was the one that came up first in the preferences window).  And yes, using GPU Compute

Comment: Strange. Have you tried selecting them one at a time to see if that makes any difference? It's hard to tell without knowing more about your setup. Noise will still take some time to clear if your scene is excessively dark or has a lot of reflections or caustics. Are you using denoising?

Comment: Is denoising possible in the viewport view of cycles?

Comment: Yes. In the render properties panel (under where you select your render engine) under _Sampling > Denoising_ Check the box and pick OptiX or the older OpenImage (or just leave it on auto).